# Chi-squared distribution and dependence

Tags: chi-squared-test, random-variable, expected-value, independence

We know that for a group of independent random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ s.t each $X_i$ is distributed as a chi-squared distribution with degree of freedom one ($\chi_1^2$), the sum of these random variables will be distributed as a chi-squared distribution with degree of freedom n ($\chi_n^2$). Let this sum be r.v $\mathcal{G}$. We know that the expectation of any of our $X_i$ is $E[X_i]=1$, so it follows that $E[\mathcal{G}]=n$.

My question: if our $X_i$'s turned out to be dependent, would we still end up with a $\chi_n^2$ r.v with expectation unaffected (we certainly know $Var[\mathcal{G}]$ will be affected)? My reasoning is that expectation is a linear operator, so we should still just be able to sum up all of our expectations without consequence. I'm new to stats, so this has been a tad confusing me.

Comment: Why tag with `non-independent` rather than `dependence`?

Comment: haha I typed in dependent and that was the option closest to dependence for me. I just changed it to dependence.

Comment: Looks like it's\* mapped to 'non-independent', so I've wasted your time there. If you type `dependence` in it will be replaced by `non-independent` anyway. My apologies.  $\qquad$ \*(oddly to my mind; though I can make a guess as to why the map goes that way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question: if our $X_i$'s turned out to be dependent, would we still end up with a $\chi_n^2$ r.v with expectation unaffected

You won't end up with a $\chi^2$ in general.

> (we certainly know $Var[\mathcal{G}]$ will be affected)

In many cases, yes, but it depends on the form of the dependence, so it's not actually certain. It's not hard to come up with forms of dependence among $n$ variables where the variance is unchanged from independence.

> My reasoning is that expectation is a linear operator,

It is.

> so we should still just be able to sum up all of our expectations without consequence.

You can. But that doesn't make the result $\chi^2$.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I realized after reading more about the chi-squared distribution that we probably would not end with such a distribution, since by definition we need to have independent squared standard normal random variables for chi-squared. 

Also, thank you for your comment regarding variance. With my knowledge of independence implying covariance would be zero, I guess I inadvertently assumed dependent variables must have non-zero covariance.